# Weird bug when variable takes the value of a object

Tags: php, variables

It's like this:

```
$var = $obj->data->field;

echo $var; // works, I get the value of 'field'

if(empty($var)) echo '$var is empty!'; // I get this message too. wtf?
```

What's the problem here? Why does empty() return true?

Comment: Is the value of the field `false`, `0`, `0.0`, `NULL`, `array()` (empty array)? Take a look at [all the cases when `empty` returns true](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: no, it's a string like 'bla bla..'

Comment: (1) What's exact value of it? (2) Are you sure that you don't have any semicolon after `if(empty($var))`? (3) Is the printed message `bla bla.. is empty!` or just `is empty!`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: `$obj->data->field` "is" an object and the class does not implement the [__isset()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) method as you'd need it in order to use empty() this way.

What does

```
echo "type:", gettype($obj->data), " class:", get_class($obj->data);
```

print?

---

self-contained example to demonstrate the effect:

```
<?php
class Bar {
    public $flag=false;
    public function __isset($key) {
        return $this->flag;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return '#'.$key.'#';
    }
}

$foo = new StdClass;
$foo->bar = new Bar;
echo empty($foo->bar->test) ? 'empty':'not empty', ", ", $foo->bar->test, "\n";

$foo->bar->flag = true;
echo empty($foo->bar->test) ? 'empty':'not empty', ", ", $foo->bar->test, "\n";
```

prints

```
empty, #test#
not empty, #test#
```

Comment: how can I find out what type of variable is it>?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, not `get_class($obj->data->field)` but `get_class($obj->data)` same with gettype().

Comment: TArticle... do you know where this is coming from? Maybe there is some documentation publicly accessible?

Comment: no, it's a class I made. Do I need to change something in it?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement the __isset() method. It must return `true` for an property that is only accessible via __get() if you want to test it with empty()   ...or you don't use empty() ;-)

Comment: I don't get it... He does not check if `$obj->data->field` is empty, he checks if `$var` is empty **after a value of `$obj->data->field` is assigned to `$var`**. `$var = $obj->data->field; if ( empty($var) ) { }` is **not** the same as `if ( empty($obj->data->field) ) { }`...

Answer (score 4):

I guess you expect that empty will return `true` only for `NULL` while actually whole set of values is considered to be "empty values"; [from doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
The following things are considered to be empty:

    * "" (an empty string)
    * 0 (0 as an integer)
    * 0.0 (0 as a float)
    * "0" (0 as a string)
    * NULL
    * FALSE
    * array() (an empty array)
    * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

Answer (score 4):

What is your variable set to? 0, false, empty strings and some others are considered empty. Try isset() instead and see if it works. In this case, you'll have to print your message when isset() is false.

Answer (score 4):

Which is the value of `$var` after gets the `$obj->data->field`?

according to the [man page](http://php.net/empty) "0" and "0.0" and others are all considered empty.